# Find header file inclusion path

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, include

I am getting a header file included in my program and I want to know how it got included (it is one of the standard include files). It is probably included by a file included by a file included...   - you get the picture. It may even be 6 or 7 includes deep (or more). How can I see where it is included from? Is there a way to get the whole `#include` tree for a `.c` file?

I am using VS2008.

Comment: I have Visual Assist if someone knows a way using that (I am new to this tool and unaware of most of what it can do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the [`/showIncludes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) switch to the compiler command line. This will print out every file being included to the output window. The output is indented to indicate which file is causing the inclusion of a particular header.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) with [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). Install both and run doxygen on your source code/libraries you will get an inclusion graph shows a wonderful tree of inclusion.

Note: once you run doxygen you get into a wizard where you can tell doxygen to get the inclusion tree and where you can point doxygen to your source code location. Doxygen uses Graphiz to draw the inclusion graphs.

Example include graphs:

simple one:
  [image: simple one]

quite complicated one:
[image: quite complicated one]